# How to use Angular 2 Universal in Angular 4.0

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am trying to learn how to make Angular 2 Universal happen.
But I can't find any good tutorials or documentation.

My Angular project is currently made with the Angular CLI 1.0 which is now on Angular 4.0. And have read that Universal is built in.

I don't even know where to start. Some of the tutorials are even outdated which is confusing and not sure if it's even worth the try. So can someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: what part of the angular universal project are you having trouble with, *exactly*?  the [official guide](https://universal.angular.io/quickstart/) that covers Angular, Webpack, and a Node.js backend is pretty self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

I think following material fits you. Also I learnt angular universal from it.
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/universal.html

Comment: The URL seems broken.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow their official Github page: https://github.com/angular/universal

It's still a work in progress:

> Angular 4.0
>
> - Integrate the platform API into core (Done)
> - Support Title and Meta services on the server (Done)
> - Write documentation for core API (In Progress)
> - Develop Express, ASP.NET Core, Hapi engines (In Progress)

If you are looking for some sample code this can be quite helpful: https://github.com/robwormald/ng-universal-demo